# When run a c++ exe in a python code, don't change text file

Tags: python, c++, text, exe

I have a c++ code that in this, i change strings in a text file.
this code run correctly. but when i run exe of this code in a python file, run correctly but don't change strings of text file.
what must i do?

part of my c++ for change text file:

```
ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << i << endl;
 myfile.close();
```

and i run exe of this code in python with this part of code:

```
os.system(mycppcode)
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it does not change the entire text file?

Comment: I edit my question. my mean is i want to write variable "i" in text. when run c++ update text but when run exe in pyhton , dont update text file.

Comment: What is `i` in the above program? Your problem isn't really clear. What is it that you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @narges We'd be very interested to know what `mycppcode` is.

Comment: Are you running your Python script in the same directory as the `example.txt` file? If not the problem is that a _new_ file is being created and the original is not touched.

Comment: "i" is a string variable. in my c++ create "i" variable and i want to write that in text file that i use this later in pyhton code. but when i run exe in python, that text was not update

Comment: @LogicStuff mycppcpde is name of exe of my c++ code

Comment: @ mhawke, my python script was not in same folder of example.txt. but when i write full address didnot work too. but when i put all codes in same folder work correctly. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your compiled cpp binary runs in a wrong directory (check your user directory for `example.txt`)

You need to specify full path to your executable in python script:

```
os.system(os.getcwd() + '/test')
```